# I can't adjust position fixed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to do, when user descents down the page, nav-bar position is fixed. I change position jquery or css but the problem is that.

First version on Site: 
[image]

When user descents down the page:

[image]

I want to fixed on top of the page. Thanks for helping.

```
nav css: `
img#logo {width:auto;height:72px;  position:absolute;margin-left:90px; }
div#nav {width:1930px;height:72px;border:2px solid #333;}
div#nav ul { list-style-type:none; }
div#nav ul li {float:left;}
div#nav ul#menu1 li a {font:20px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; padding:160px; color:#333;line-height:72px;}
div#nav ul#menu2 li a {font:20px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;padding:160px;margin-left:160px; color:#333; line-height:72px;}`
```

jquery:

```
 $(window).scroll(function(e)
    {
        var location = $(window).scrollTop();
        if(location>=$('div#nav').offset().top)
        {
            $('div#nav').css({'position':'fixed'});
        }
    });
```

Comment: can you post code what you tried in html,jquery?

Comment: ah sorry, ı was forget. I add now

Comment: If the position is always at the bottom, why don't you just always have the position as fixed?

Comment: try this - `$('div#nav').css({'position':'fixed', 'top':0});

Comment: thanks, it works :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to use https://fixedposition.googlecode.com/files/jquery.fixedposition.1.0.0-min.js for this purpose, because this works easy and fine.

First include the .js file in the header of your website, and then use the followig code:

```
 <script>
        $(document).scroll(function(){
            if( !$('.navbar').length ) return;

            if (!$('.navbar').attr('data-top')) {

                // If already fixed, then do nothing
                if ($('.navbar').hasClass('navbar-fixed')) return;

                // Remember top position
                var offset = $('.navbar').offset();

                $('.navbar').attr('data-top', offset.top);
            }


            if ($('.navbar').attr('data-top') <= $(this).scrollTop()) {
                $('body').addClass('subnav-active');
                $('.navbar').addClass('navbar-fixed');
                $('#navbarStyleHolder').css("display", "block");
            }

            else {
                $('body').removeClass('subnav-active');
                $('.navbar').removeClass('navbar-fixed');
                $('#navbarStyleHoler').css("display", "none");
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Next just go ahead and replace `.navbar` with your div in which your nav is in, and then create a `.css` class with the formatting your fixed header should have (in my example code called `.navbar-fixed` ).

This script will automatically replace the `.navbar` class with the `.navbar-fixed` class when reaching the end of the `.navbar` div.

For example if you want to have it on top of the screen, use this css code:

```
.navbar-fixed {
position:fixed;
top:1;
}
```

Comment: thanks for helping.:). That's be fixed But How I use js effects ?